# H1B Temporary Worker/ 1099 MISC Income

Tags: united-states, income-tax, legal, form-1099-misc, h-1b-visa

I am a H1B temporary worker in the united states at the moment. Last year, there was a pilot TV series filming in our apartment of residence which resulted in some inconvenience for me as a resident. The corresponding firm compensated me with 600$ accordingly and sent me a 1099 MISC filled in BOX-7(600$).

I just wanted to understand if this is legal as a H1B worker. Please advice on the following.

If this is not legal, what should be my next steps before filing my taxes ?

1. How do I cancel the payment and return the money ?
2. Is it legal and possible to re purpose the payment for a 1099 MISC under a different category that legal explains the compensation ?